# Python operator.methodcaller() not processing arguments correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to use the `operator.methodcaller()` function in python inside a mapping function. However, I am receiving weird error messages when passing argument lists.

The python documentation leads me to believe, that this should normally not be a problem:

> Return a callable object that calls the method name on its operand. If additional arguments and/or keyword arguments are given, they will be given to the method as well. For example:
>
> After f = methodcaller('name'), the call f(b) returns b.name().
>
> After f = methodcaller('name', 'foo', bar=1), the call f(b) returns b.name('foo', bar=1).

Where am I going wrong here? Are there any simple alternatives?

I have made up a short code example to illustrate my problem:

```
import operator

class CallTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2

    def mutate(self, new_x, some_y = 2):
        self.x = new_x
        self.y = some_y

def map_something(func, iterable):
    """ This doesn't work and that's as expected. The error shows that the methodcaller is referencing
        the correct object though.
    """
    for i in iterable:
        func(i)

def map_something_else(func, iterable, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Why doesn't this work? And are there alternatives? """
    for i in iterable:
        func(i, *args, **kwargs)

def map_differently(func, iterable, *args, **kwargs):
    """ This works as expected but is kind of pointless in this case because i could replace this
        with getattr()
    """
    for i in iterable:
        operator.methodcaller(func, *args, ** kwargs)(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    caller = operator.methodcaller('mutate')

    objs = [CallTest() for i in range(0, 2)]
    # map_something(caller, objs) # As expected we get: TypeError: mutate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_x'

    # map_something_else(caller, objs, 5) # TypeError: methodcaller expected 1 argument, got 2

    # map_something_else(caller, objs, 5, some_y=3) # TypeError: methodcaller() takes no keyword arguments

    map_differently('mutate', objs, 5, some_y=3) # This works as expected.

    for obj in objs:
        print(obj.x, obj.y)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator.methodcaller` only takes additional arguments on creation. You're trying to provide the extra arguments when the methodcaller is called.

It works like this:

```
mc = operator.methodcaller('method_name', additional_arg)
mc(obj)
```

Not like this:

```
mc = operator.methodcaller('method_name')
mc(obj, additional_arg)
```

which is what your `map_something_else` is trying to do.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess that's also exactly what it says in the documentation if I read it again now.